# Scoping mat file in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I load a .mat file to Simulink and I need its values one-by-one. However, the from file block loads all data at once. Thus, in the scope, the data appears as a set of constant values rather than a wave function.

I need to use this data separately and plot it as a wave in the scope.

Comment: Load the data into the base workspace before your simulation and then use the FromWorkspace block? There's a few different ways you can specify which time sample each value corresponds to, e.g. if the data is a Timeseries, or a 2-column array of time/data

Comment: I create timeseries with the code snippet above, and did what you said. But now I can only see 51 data point instead of 35000 which supposed to be like that

`load('testVals.mat');`
`sampleTime = 0.01;`
`numSteps = 35001;`
`time = sampleTime*[0:(numSteps-1)];`
`data = testVals;`
`time = time';
`inputData = timeseries(data,time);`
`save("inputData.mat","inputData","-v7.3"); `

Comment: What sample time is your model actually running at? Does it actually use the `sampleTime` variable or is it hard-coded in the model configuration? Are you using a fixed step solver with a 0.01sec stepsize or a variable step solver in which case Simulink may skip points? You have not included enough information in your question to reproduce the issue, please do so by [edit]ing the question - take the [tour] and read [ask] to understand why that's required